Where is the following verse found? (alir bāṇo jyotiṣakaḥ...)
Where is this verse found?

alir bāṇo jyotiṣakaḥ
stabdhībhūtaḥ kimekakaḥ
preṣita-preṣakaś caiva
ṣaḍ ete sevakādhamāḥ


This is not a translation forum.

Sir i have not asked for translation..i have asked to point out the source of the verse

I have a question can an Aryan take initiation from a mleccha?  What do the scriptures say?

Possibly from an older version of the Neeti Shataka which is no longer available. It must have been available few centuries ago when the authors who quoted it composed their respective texts.

unkown source yet there are multiple commentaries and translations available
